# Change CSS classes with jQuery independently for two similar elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have two similar HTML blocks (one for news and the second for special offers), they both have pagination buttons in the bottom, so i tried to build a universal function to change pagination buttons state (active/inactive) independently for each block, but i failed. And that is the question. How can i do it?

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamsvyat/5TjKQ/

HTML:

```
<div id="news-block">News Block</div>
<div class="pag-circles">
    <button class="pag-circle-1 active">&nbsp;</button>
    <button class="pag-circle-2 inactive">&nbsp;</button>
    <button class="pag-circle-3 inactive">&nbsp;</button>
    <button class="pag-circle-4 inactive">&nbsp;</button>
</div>
<div id="special-offers-block">Special Offers Block</div>
<div class="pag-circles">
    <button class="pag-circle-1 active">&nbsp;</button>
    <button class="pag-circle-2 inactive">&nbsp;</button>
    <button class="pag-circle-3 inactive">&nbsp;</button>
    <button class="pag-circle-4 inactive">&nbsp;</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 6px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.active {
    border-color: red;
}
.inactive {
    border-color: black;
}
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#news-block").next(".pag-circles").children().click(function() {
    //if the first button is clicked
    //if the second button is clicked
    //if the third button is clicked
    //if the fourth button is clicked
});
$("#special-offers-block").next(".pag-circles").children().click(function() {
    //if the first button is clicked
    //if the second button is clicked
    //if the third button is clicked
    //if the fourth button is clicked
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to give the buttons the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this revision using event delegation [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5TjKQ/6/)

```
$("#firstCommonAncestor").on('click', 'button',function (e) {
    var t = $(this);
    t.addClass('active').removeClass('inactive').siblings().removeClass('active').addClass('inactive')
});
```

Comment: You're welcome ! [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is easy to read and understand, have a look if not done already `;)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this technically works: http://jsfiddle.net/5TjKQ/8/

I had to give your `pag-circles` class `div`'s some id's though.

Answer (score 1):

well you can use a attirbute selector with `^` or give same class to both and use class selector.

```
$('button[class^="pag-circle-"]').click(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('inactive')
          .addClass("active")
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('active')
          .addClass("inactive");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TjKQ/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5TjKQ/10/

You can get the clicked button's reference and add/remove relevant classes as below

```
$('.pag-circles button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active'); 
});
```

Also you will need to update the rest of the buttons' classes too. $.each function will do the trick. Checkout the js fiddle link given above for full solution.